# Check the manual the corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use

Tags: sql, sql-update, mariadb, common-table-expression

I'm trying to make a sql syntax:

```sql
UPDATE `%s`
JOIN (WITH t2 AS
(
SELECT LAG(storymain_id,1) OVER (ORDER BY storymain_id) AS lg, `%s`.* 
FROM `%s`
)
SELECT t2.*,
1 + SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(lg,storymain_id) = storymain_id THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) 
OVER (ORDER BY storymain_id) AS new_id
FROM t2 ) t2
ON `%s`.storymain_id = t2.storymain_id SET `%s`.storymain_id = t2.new_id;
```

on my maria-db server, which version is:

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.44-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

I got an error when I run it:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]:
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MariaDB Server version for the right syntax to use near 't2 AS\r\n\t\t\t\t 
(\r\n\t\t\t\t\tSELECT LAG(storymain_id, 1) OVER (ORDER BY storymain_id) AS' at line ~.
```

I need to make it work, but I don't know how to change the syntax..

Thanks for your help...

Comment: If it's pure SQL syntax (using python) it's not allowed to have placeholders for tables, views or stored procedures,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just replaced the cte with a normal derived table. You are not using the cte only once in the query, so it doesn't really matter:

```
update `%s`
join (
    select 
        t2.*,
        1 + sum(case when coalesce(lg,storymain_id) = storymain_id then 0 else 1 end) 
            over (order by storymain_id) as new_id
    from (
        select 
            lag(storymain_id,1) over (order by storymain_id) as lg, 
            `%s`.* 
        from `%s`
    ) t2
) t2
on `%s`.storymain_id = t2.storymain_id 
set `%s`.storymain_id = t2.new_id;
```

Otherwise, MySQL wants the `with` clause at the beginning o the statement:

```
with t2 as (
    select 
        lag(storymain_id,1) over (order by storymain_id) as lg, 
        `%s`.* 
    from `%s`
)
update `%s`
join (
    select 
        t2.*,
        1 + sum(case when coalesce(lg,storymain_id) = storymain_id then 0 else 1 end) 
            over (order by storymain_id) as new_id
    from t2
) t
on `%s`.storymain_id = t.storymain_id 
set `%s`.storymain_id = t.new_id;
```

**[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html)**:

> A WITH clause is permitted in these contexts:
>
> - At the beginning of SELECT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements.
>
>   `WITH ... SELECT ...`
>
>   `WITH ... UPDATE ...`
>
>   `WITH ... DELETE ...`